# Should I use Postgres's roles system for a web app's user management?

Tags: php, postgresql, web-applications

Postgres already has fully featured user management system. Why should I duplicate this functionality and use another one on top of that? And I think this is the right place to manage users & groups as it allows fine-grained control. Am I wrong? Is there some php libraries that already have done that?
I should add that the app in question is not a public web-site, but a corporate app working in the private network.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I strongly advocate that application designers make use of PostgreSQL's users and role system ... but for a number of reasons having a 1:1 mapping of app users to database users is not usually practical.

- PostgreSQL roles are shared across *all databases* (though they don't have to be granted rights on anything except one)
- You can't have a foreign key reference from a normal application table to a PostgreSQL user table
- There's no function or other interface to authenticate a user by password. You have to make a new connection to authenticate by password. This breaks connection pooling.

Instead, I advise that you use a couple of *roles* in the database:

- A database owner role. This user/role owns the database and the tables within it. Scripts to change the database structure ("migrations" and so on) run as this user.
- A webapp role. This is the role the app connects as when establishing pooled connections. This is `GRANT`ed only the access the app needs when running day to day. It can't change table structure, drop tables, etc. If a table is supposed to be append-only you don't grant `UPDATE` rights to this role.
- (possibly) some maintenance roles for scripts, etc, which have limited access to just what they need for their task.

You manage your application users with normal tables.

Sometimes you also want additional database roles for particular categories of user. This can be handy if you're dealing with apps with different privilege levels, departments, etc. The webapp can `SET ROLE` to switch roles, so if "joe" connects and you know "joe" is in accounts, you "SET ROLE accounts" before running queries for joe. This is more advanced, and most people don't need it.

The main time I think using PostgreSQL user management directly makes sense is when the app has quite complex access requirements and doesn't need a huge profusion of different users (thousands, rather than millions). For webapps I'd stick with normal database tables and just separate a "db admin"role from the webapp connection pool role.

Comment: Given that the app is in PHP (no connection pooling problem) and will be used in a corporate network (mostly hundreds of users at a time) and it does need advanced access management (I'm waiting for the RLS in 9.5) will you still not recommend to use it?

Comment: @nii Saying that PHP means there's no connection pooling concern doesn't make sense. You can use a pool in PHP, or a proxy pool like PgBouncer, and it's very common to do so. However, with hundreds of concurrent users you might not need to. If you're looking at using RLS, etc, then it might well be worth doing. The advantage to having in-DB users is that you can `GRANT` each user the specific roles they need, and in turn `GRANT` those roles only the specific rights they require.

Comment: You are right about connection pooling, I didn't read it right first time, it might be necessary in the future. And now I think that I just can use several roles with different RLS access rights for different departments and stick to the app-level user management system.

Comment: To add to your answer, there is another case when the db-level user management is the right choice: when one database is used by multiple applications

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this is not done, although possible.

Your application would not be portable to other databases, and mysql is quite popular for web apps.

Instead you normally design your users table to your own needs, and write groups and access management yourself, or use one of the many libraries.

(an upvote for noticing the PG role system)

Comment: Thinking to be portable to other databases is the same as being portable to other languages. This means using the least common features from all rdbms (eg mysql). Useful if your dev is a vanilla forum software, counter productive if your development is a dedicated business oriented application.

Comment: I don't think there will be a need to port my application to another DBMS. And thus tying it to Postgres -- the best open-source DBMS -- will not be a bad thing.

Comment: @greg I have written my user and group management in pltcl (using bit strings) to be portable to other languages / batch access, without PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You do not use your OS's user management in your application because each layer uses users to grant rights on objects it manages. OS have users to grant privileges on processus, files etc. RDBMS have users to grant privileges on tables, schemas, sequences etc.

Theses users might not be used in your application layer where business oriented objects thus permissions are differents.

Comment: Great to hear your opinion. Thank you for the Pomm BTW, I'm using it heavily in this app.